# Easy computation by Ravi Vakil (jet bundles)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, characteristic-classes, jet-bundles

I landed on some short notes by Ravi Vakil from the 90s, the *Beginner's Guide to Jet Bundles from the Point of View of Algebraic Geometry*.

The notes are very clear but on the very first page there is an easy computation whose result seems wrong to me. We are working on $\mathbb P^2$ an Vakil says that
$$ c_2(\mathcal O(d) \otimes (\mathcal O \oplus \Omega))=3(d-1)^2$$
EDIT: where $\Omega=T^*\mathbb P^2$ is the cotangent bundle.

If we call $H$ the hyperplane class in $A\mathbb P^2$, I think that the total Chern class for $\Omega$ is
$$c(\Omega)=1-3H+6H^2 \ \ (\star)$$
If $(\star)$ above is correct, we should have that
$$c_2(\mathcal O(d)\oplus \Omega(d))=d^2 + (2d-3)\cdot d+(d^2-3d+3),\ \ (\square)$$
which is not the above value.

I couldn't find anyone pointing this error out on the internet, therefore I'm supposing that I am the one who is wrong: I think that my mistake is somewhere in the $(\square)$ evaluation, and maybe I am missing something about the general techniques of evaluation of total Chern classes.

Comment: Does $\Omega$ denote the cotangent bundle?

Comment: Yes, I'm going to precise that in the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $(\star)$ is incorrect.

We have $c(\Omega) = 1 - 3H + 3H^2$ because $\Omega = T^*\mathbb{CP}^2 \cong \overline{T\mathbb{CP}^2}$, $c_i(\overline{E}) = (-1)^ic_i(E)$, and $c(T\mathbb{CP}^2) = (1 + H)^3 = 1 + 3H + 3H^2$.

By using the formula for $c_2(V\otimes L)$ from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4322406/39599), we obtain the correct conclusion:

\begin{align*}
c_2(\mathcal{O}(d)\otimes(\mathcal{O}\oplus\Omega)) &= c_2(\mathcal{O}\oplus\Omega) + (3-1)c_1(\mathcal{O}(d))c_1(\mathcal{O}\oplus\Omega) + \binom{3}{2}c_1(\mathcal{O}(d))^2\\
&= c_2(\Omega) + 2c_1(\mathcal{O}(d))c_1(\Omega) + 3c_1(\mathcal{O}(d))^2\\
&= 3H^2 + 2dH(-3H) + 3(dH)^2\\
&= 3H^2 -6dH^2 + 3d^2H^2\\
&= (3d^2 - 6d + 3)H^2\\
&= 3(d^2 - 2d + 1)H^2\\
&= 3(d-1)^2H^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: The $6$ in the $(\star)$ was just a typo, but in fact in the calculations I think I evaluated the second chern class of a line bundle (finally accounting for the extra $d^2$). Thank you for your answer